# Cake Build: Collecting environment variables from cmd file

Tags: cakebuild

I want to run a a project with msbuild. The msbuild file contains references to environment variables.

There is a cmd-file which will set these environment variables. I need to call it from my Cake script before.

If I use StartProcess to call this cmd-file before I start the compiler it won't work because Cake does not collect environment variables.

How do I call the cmd-file the correct way?

Contents of the batch-file:

```
@SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0
@SET BDSINCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\include
@SET BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
@SET FrameworkVersion=v3.5
@SET FrameworkSDKDir=
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%FrameworkSDKDir%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin64;%PATH%
@SET LANGDIR=DE
```

Answer (score 0):

The StartProcess Alias has an overload which accepts a [ProcessSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/ProcessSettings/) object, which contains an [EnvironmentVariables](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.IO/ProcessSettings/897B45AB) property, which is just a generic dictionary of string and string.  This allows you to construct any environment variables that need to be passed to the process that you want to start.  An example would be the following:

```
StartProcess("cmd", new ProcessSettings{
    Arguments = "/c set",
    EnvironmentVariables = new Dictionary<string, string>{
        { "CI", "True" },
        { "TEMP", MakeAbsolute(Directory("./Temp")).FullPath }
    }
});
```

The same technique could also be used to call MSBuild directly, rather than using the batch file, as the [MSBuildSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildSettings/) object has the same property.

Comment: I don't want to maintain the required environment variables in my cake build file as they are already in the provided batch file. So the question is how to "mount" the environment variables defined in the batch file into my cake build process.

Comment: Is it possible that you can update your question with the contents of your batch file?  If they are truly environment variables as you say, then I am a little lost as to exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the question. I want to use msbuild to compile a delphi project which requires a call to a batch-file provided with the delphi compiler. Each delphi-compiler version comes with her own batch-file and I need to compile multiple projects which rely on different compiler options, so calling the batch file before I call my cake script won't work.

Comment: okay, so I see the problem now.  You said you are using environment variables, and in a way, you are, however, those changes are only present in the context of the current CMD execution, and therefore not available to the next command that you are running: https://ss64.com/nt/set.html  This is a similar approach to what I was suggesting above.  Do you "need" to shell out to the batch file?  Can you not simply call the delphi-compiler directly?

Comment: That's correct. I could copy the contents of the environment variables into my build script but in the case of updates to the compiler etc. I have to watch out and sync them manually if they change. So it would be more of a workaround than a solution for me. The batch files are actually provided with the compiler itself so it would be the best to use them.

Comment: The only thing that I can suggest would be to parse that batch file into your Cake Script, and then create a Dictionary of Environment Variables, which you could then pass through to MSBuild, using the technique that I have shown above.